# 500 Internal Server Error - Hospedagem UOL Host

Tags: php

Eu desenvolvi um site simples para armazenar informações de cadastro usando código PHP e banco de dados MySQL.

O sistema funciona perfeitamente no ambiente de teste (XAMPP for Windows 7.2.0 rodando PHP 7.2.1), mas ao rodar no ambiente de produção (Hospedagem UOL Host com PHP 7.1), ocasionalmente recebo o erro do servidor "500 Internal Server Error" no navegador, e não é em nenhuma página específica, acontece aparentemente de maneira aleatória.

Eu conversei com o suporte do UOL Host e eles disseram que pode ser algum problema em meu código PHP, mas eu não sei nem por onde começar a investigar, sendo que em todos os testes que faço em meu ambiente de teste, o erro nunca ocorre. Me parece que pode ser algum problema de configuração na instalação compartilhada do PHP do UOL.

Verifiquei o log do PHP em produção, mas não localizei nada que possa estar indicando a causa do erro.

Comment: Ativa o modo DEBUG no log do seu site se houver e do PHP. Erro 500 é bem chato e pode ser várias coisas.

Comment: Olha o log de erro do apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou compartilhar com vocês a solução que encontrei para o problema, sendo que sem dúvida não é a melhor, porém é o que eu consegui fazer, considerando que o suporte da hospedagem 'UOL Host' é péssimo.. os analistas de lá parecem robôs que só respondem algumas frases prontas e dificilmente nos ajudam eficientemente a resolver os problemas.

Bem, pelo que eu pesquisei nos foruns, inclusive aqui no Stack Overflow, tudo indica que o problema envolve permissões de acesso a diretórios linux. Mas o suporte do UOL Host não foi capaz de me ajudar a alterar os privilégios das pastas da minha hospedagem.

Então, considerando que o provedor oferece a opção de migrar os arquivos da hospedagem em ambiente linux para o ambiente Windows, eu solicitei esta migração e depois disso, o problema ficou resolvido. Eu usei a lógica de que o sistema operacional Windows é muito menos exigente com relação a permissões de acesso a diretórios.

Enfim, foi uma solução drástica, porém funcional, e pode ajudar outros usuários do provedor UOL Host ou semelhantes.